# Trying to print out data from Excel column with Python script but the DataFrame is empty

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I'm a novice so this might be an easy fix, but I am trying to print out the data of a column in Excel but it says that it's empty even though it isn't.

This is what it says in the terminal:

**Empty DataFrame**

**Columns: [test]**

**Index: []**

[My column in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSk23.png)

This is my python script:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

mydir = os.getcwd().replace('\\', '/') + '/'

df = pd.read_excel(mydir + 'Excel-test.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', header=0)

print(df)
```

I've tried changing formats in the cells but didn't work.

Comment: Should work. Try adding more rows

Comment: @gtomer Tried adding more rows but it still says it's empty

Comment: Code works fine. It gives a DF with one column named **test** and one row with value **test**. Using `header = None` would give two rows.

Comment: Try upgrading pandas and openpyxl

Comment: @user19077881 I tried putting header to None and got this in the terminal:
      0
0  test

And I've now added about 20 rows in the same column.

Comment: Are you sure the sheet is named "Sheet1" ?
Btw, instead of using ` os.getcwd().replace('\\', '/') + '/' `, take a look at os.path.join and raw strings